# What is happening in this photo?

Tags: moon, nasa, space-flight

Yesterday I saw the following photo in a book, which is taken during the [Apollo 12 mission](http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo12/hires/as12-49-7278.jpg):

[image]

I see at least some significant odd things about this picture:

- Why the directions of shadows do not totally agree with the light source?
- Why the horizon in the reflection and the one in the photo are alligned (see [this](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/600875main_BeanonApollo12.jpg) for instance)? And what is that shiny thing at upper left corner? Is it the Sun or a planet or a candle?:)

I am not a conspiracy theorist. I just don't understand what is happening in the picture. Maybe there are multiple light sources, the image is rotated, edited  etc...

I will accept the most creative theory as the answer. Feel free to free your imagination.

Comment: I don't think "most creative theory" is going to fly here...

Comment: "I will accept the most creative theory as the answer.", please don't.

Answer (score 10):

The reflection of the light off of one astronaut's suit is a significant source of light/shadow, so yes, in effect, there are multiple light sources. http://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2014/09/18/debunked/

The light at the top left is an internal reflection/lens flare.

The horizons line up because that is how the helmet, camera, and horizon happen to be aligned.

You are [anomaly hunting](http://theness.com/neurologicablog/index.php/anomaly-hunting/).

Comment: In addition to what Dawn pointed out you are noting the shadows not lining up perfectly--but that's actually to be expected if the terrain isn't perfectly flat. In an image like this our depth perception doesn't work very well so we are fooled into thinking the shadows are wrong.